# Smart Card Authentication with ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, authentication, smartcard

What are the steps required to get smart-cards authentication working in ASP.net?

- Smart-card reader is installed and works properly on the client's machine
- user navigates to Login.aspx page and is prompted to swipe his access card
- how do i authenticate the user

thanks.

Comment: What's the Make & Model of your smart card reader?  Can't even begin to help without this.

Comment: ACR 122 U from ACS it's a windows plug and play device. i am able to access it from vb.net windows and console applications.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only way that I know to access a hardware device on a client machine through ASP.Net is by writing an ActiveX control. Doing this will render the site useless to anyone not running Internet Explorer. Based on my experience, you can say that IE is your standard, but there will be people attempting to use other browsers. And that's fine as long as you have the support of your App Admin team to say, "Sorry, use IE or don't use it at all".

Comment: I've just written an activeX control for this. I will also investigate  doing plugins for chrome & fire fox.

Comment: Could you please explain more about the ActiveX you've written? If you're interested, you can start an open source project and people will help to write chrome/firefox/etc. plugins.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you already know how to access the Smart Card reader's API, and you can successfully read and decode that data, your next step is Authenticating that data.

Again, you haven't given me any information here, so I'll assume that you have a database, against which you will need to validate the data you got from the smart card.

If the above returns true then it's simply a case of calling `FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage`, or if you want a more granular control of the Authentication Cookie, then you can create your own `FormsAuthenticationTicket`

Comment: hi Jaimal, are you saying that i don't need to configure anything special on IIS? Also, how will the asp.net web application access the data from the smart card? that's the main issue

Answer (score 0):

If this is a plug and play device and your clients are part of an AD domain then by simply enabling windows authentication allows you to enable smart card authentication without needing to resort to custom ActiveX controls and browser plugins.

A couple of pointers in that direction:

- [IIS supports client certificates](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732116.aspx)
- [IIS Forum thread: Configuring IIS 7.5 to read certificates from a smart card](http://forums.iis.net/t/1165336.aspx)

Comment: the clients are not on an AD domain